# Notification when my form is fully loaded in C# (.Net Compact Framework)?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I have a form in my application and I want to do some processing when my form has been

Fully loaded but I have no event or something which I can bind to when load is finished.

Does anyone has any idea, how can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What exaclty mean "fully loaded" ? Do you mean, the "Load" event was successfully proceeded?

You can do this:

```
public class MyForm : Form {
    protected override void OnLoad( EventArgs e ) {
        // the base method raises the load method
        base.OnLoad( e );

        // now are all events hooked to "Load" method proceeded => the form is loaded
        this.OnLoadComplete( e );
    }

    // your "special" method to handle "load is complete" event
    protected virtual void OnLoadComplete ( e ) { ... }
}
```

But if you mean "fully loaded" the "form is loaded AND shown" you need override the "OnPaint" method too.

```
public class MyForm : Form {
    private bool isLoaded;
    protected override void OnLoad( EventArgs e ) {
        // the base method raises the load method
        base.OnLoad( e );

        // notify the "Load" method is complete
        this.isLoaded = true;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint( PaintEventArgs e ) {
        // the base method process the painting
        base.OnPaint( e );

        // this method can be theoretically called before the "Load" event is proceeded
        // , therefore is required to check if "isLoaded == true"
        if ( this.isLoaded ) {
            // now are all events hooked to "Load" method proceeded => the form is loaded
            this.OnLoadComplete( e );
        }
    }

    // your "special" method to handle "load is complete" event
    protected virtual void OnLoadComplete ( e ) { ... }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe nobody has brought this up yet... base.Load( e ); produces an error, `The event 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.Load' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=`.  But this method still does not work for me. The OnLoadComplete() fires before the form is even show. :(

Comment: Thats probably because something invoked the OnPaint() method before the form is shown. Try set breakpoint there and investigate the callstack.

Comment: I have a brand new application and ONLY have the app do the following.  App starts, and after the form is completely finished, it will show a splash screen. So from what I can see, this is the order of events...  frm1:OnLoad starts, frm1:Load starts, frm1:Load ends, frm1:OnLoad ends, frm1:OnPaint starts, frm2:Load starts, frm2:Load ends, frm2:DoubleClick starts, frm2:Closes, frm2:DoubleClick stops, frm1:OnPaint ends.  So basicly, frm1 loads and before it finishes popping up (mid way) frm2 pops up instantly, then frm1 takes focus again, then frm2 takes final focus. Note: frm2 is borderless.

Comment: .Net Framework 4 Client Profile, but nevermind don't worry about it.  I ended up taking a different approach.  The direction I was heading was a bad design anyway.  The frm2 form should simply load first, do what it needs to THEN load frm1.  ;)  - Sorry for the wasted time.

Answer (score 4):

I think the `OnLoad` event isn't really what you want, as it occurs *before* the form is displayed. You can use `Application.Idle` with `OnLoad` to make an `OnLoaded` event though:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs args)
{
    Application.Idle += new EventHandler(OnLoaded);
}

public void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   Application.Idle -= new EventHandler(OnLoaded);
   // rest of your code 
}
```

Comment: But the Application.Idle can be raised a long time after the form is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use the OnLoad event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onload.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My approach is similar to the accepted answer from TcKs.
The problem I faced was that I had an event handler for a group of controls that responded to VisibleChanged with the event handler moving controls about within a Panel. Trouble was (of course) that the Visibility changes when the form is first loaded - but after the .Load() event.

I created and set a bool value for the Form:

```
private bool formShown = false;
```

and then added the following line to the Form_Load()

```
this.Paint += (s, args) => { formShown = true; };
```

with the first line of my VisibleChanged() event handler as:

```
if(!formShown) { return; }
```

Succinct and functional.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Load` event of the form. In the constructor of your Form write following line

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
```

and then write the following method in which you can do some stuff.

```
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do some stuff here.
}
```

Comment: -1 because, if you hook the Load event, you can not know if something else method is not hooked "after" this method. For proper function is necesary overriding the "OnLoad" method.