# Check if the form is loaded

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two forms.

- One of them is the main form (let's call it MainForm)
- the other one is for showing some warning (let's call it dialogForm)

. dialogForm has a label in it. When i click a button in MainForm, dialogForm opens.
 But label in dialogForm is blank. It doesn't have time to load actually. I want to check if the dialogForm fully loaded then proccess can continue in MainForm.
 For example:

```
dialogForm tempFrm = new dialogForm();
tempFrm.Show(); // I want to wait till the dialogForm is fully loaded. Then continue to "while" loop.
while(..)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Call tempFrm.Update().  Using long while loops in UI code is fundamentally the wrong thing to do.  Don't do it.

Comment: What is a goal that are you hunting for?

Comment: @Hans your tempFrm.Update() suggestion  solved the problem. By the way there wasn't a while loop in orginal code. It was just an example :) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can't get good answers if you post fake code :(

Comment: @HansPassant If you post your "tempFrm.Update()" solution as an answer, I can accept it. This question has almost a 1000 views. And people can miss your answer here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not create a boolean value, and a method to access it..

```
private bool Ready = false;

public ConstructorMethod()
{
    // Constructor code etc.
    Ready = true;
}

public bool isReady()
{
    return Ready;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try the following

```
private bool Is_Form_Loaded_Already(string FormName)
            {
                foreach (Form form_loaded in Application.OpenForms)
                {
                    if (form_loaded.Text.IndexOf(FormName) >= 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
```

you can also look in this

[Notification when my form is fully loaded in C# (.Net Compact Framework)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243788/notification-when-my-form-is-fully-loaded-in-c-sharp-net-compact-framework)

Answer (score 1):

So you need to consume the forms `Shown` event:

```
tempFrm.Shown += (s, e) =>
{
    while(..)
    {
    }
}
```

But you're going to have another problem. It's going to block the thread. You need to run this `while` loop on another thread by leveraging a `BackgroundWorker` or `Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

Your while(...) blocks the UI thread so child form will never got messages and will not be loaded.

To achive you goal you should subscribe to the Load event and continue your code in the handler.

```
void Click()
{
    var tempFrm = new dialogForm();
    tempFrm.Load += frmLoad;
    tempFrm.Show();
}

void frmLoad(object s, EventArgs ea)
{
   // form loaded continue your code here!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Form.IsActive property.

Or just;

```
public bool IsFormLoaded;

public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load += new System.EventHandler(FormLoaded);
    }
private void FormLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsFormLoaded = true;
    }
```

and check if YourForm.IsFormLoaded, true or false

Comment: Before the edit, it was better. Here, can you [edit] to more explain more why and how this should fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the form's `Created` property.

> Gets a value indicating whether the control has been created.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.created?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Here is how I'm using it to check whether a `Form` has actually been created before activating it from another thread:

```
public MyForm()
{

    ...
    
    public void beginInvokeActivate()
    {
        if (!Created) return;
        BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            Activate();
        }));
    }
}
```